# ERROR: 1822 SQL MISSING INDEX ADDING FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

```
drop table if exists conexiones_clientes;
create table conexiones_clientes(
    ID int primary key auto_increment,
    NOMBRE varchar(50) not null,
    WEB varchar(50),
    CONTACTO varchar(50),
    CONTACTO2 varchar(50),
    MAIL varchar(50)
);

drop table if exists conexiones;
create table conexiones(
    ID int auto_increment,
    NOMBRE varchar(50) not null,
    TIPO_CONEXION varchar(50),
    DIRECCIÓN varchar(50),
    USUARIO varchar(50),
    CONTRASEÑA varchar(50),
    OTRA_INFORMACION varchar(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, NOMBRE),
    CONSTRAINT fknombre2conexiones FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE) REFERENCES conexiones_clientes(NOMBRE)
);
```

When i'm trying to make the second table it said me this:
Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fknombre2conexiones' in the referenced table 'conexiones_clientes'

Comment: Missing index for constraint 'fknombre2conexiones' in the referenced table 'conexiones_clientes' - Can't add to this.. Please review Conditions and Restrictions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key creation needs in the index existence in the table which you refer on. It will be used for fast integrity check. The index expression must match the foreign key expression.

In your particular case you must create unique index in `conexiones_clientes` by `(NOMBRE)`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78045acf37c6ad556cffac19dfb86296